# split implementation using vectors and char*

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to split a char* based on a delimiter using nested vectors however the last word of the char* seems to not be added to the vector>

```
vector<vector<char>> split(char* word, const char de){
    vector<vector<char>> words;
    vector<char> c_word;
    while(*word){
        if(*word == de){
            words.push_back(c_word);
            c_word.clear();
            word++;
            continue;
        }
        c_word.push_back(*word);
        word++;
    }
    return words;
}
```

Example usage:

```
int main() {
    char *let = "Hello world!";

    vector<vector<char>> words = split(let, ' ');
    for(int x = 0;x < words.size();x++){
        for(int y = 0;y < words[x].size();y++){
            cout << words[x][y];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

This would print only Hello

Comment: can you provide a code with input so one can try it ? www.ideone.com

Comment: Is there a reason you use `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` instead of `std::vector<string>`? And `char*` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: Unless the last char is the delimiter, you will still have a word in `c_word` when the loop is finished.

Comment: why not using a std::string and use index of (' ') and cut the string

Comment: Because it's a class asignment to split a char* without using string

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string

Answer (score -1):

Here is a full working code with multiple delimeters

```
vector<vector<char>> split(char* word, const char de) {
    vector<vector<char>> words;
    vector<char> c_word;
    int index = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char *temp = word;
    int numspaces = 0;
    while (*word) {
        if (*word == de) {
            words.push_back(c_word);
            c_word.clear();
            word++;
            j = index;
            numspaces++;
        }
        index++;
        c_word.push_back(*word);
        word++;
    }
    j +=numspaces;
    char *sub = &temp[j];
    c_word.clear();
    while (*sub)
    {
        c_word.push_back(*sub);
        sub++;
    }
    words.push_back(c_word);
    return words;
}
void main()
{
    vector<vector<char>> result = split("Hello World! Ahmed Saleh", ' ');

}
```

Answer (score -2):

For anyone else wondering how to do this implementation using char* instead of string. What my code is missing is a final add of c_word to words since the while is already over when it reaches the null terminator and doesn't add the final word, this is the fixed code:

```
   vector<vector<char>> split(char* word, const char de){
    vector<vector<char>> words;
    vector<char> c_word;
    while(*word){
        if(*word == de){
            words.push_back(c_word);
            c_word.clear();
            word++;
            continue;
        }
        c_word.push_back(*word);
        word++;
    }
    words.push_back(c_word);
    return words;
}
```